# Running Windows XP batch on Windows 7

Tags: java, jython, lotus-notes

I have a batch file which runs on XP:

```
@echo off
@setlocal 
set CWD=%~dp0
set JYTHON_HOME=%CWD%
set LIB_DIR=%JYTHON_HOME%/lib
java -cp %LIB_DIR% -jar %LIB_DIR%/jython.jar -Djython.home=%CWD%
-Dpython.path=%LIB_DIR%;%CWD%/ext %LIB_DIR%clenotes/clenotes.py %* 
@endlocal
```

I want to run this file on Windows 7.

**EDIT:**

When I run it this error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
folder\CLENotes\lib Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
folder\CLENotes\lib
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hm, what happens if you run it on 7?

Comment: Does it work, not work, cause your computer to burst into flame?

Comment: What is supposed to happen? What is "clenotes.py" doing?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is very simple, I needed to change the fowardslashes (`/`) to backslashes.